# Maintaining default open/close behavior with custom ValueContainer in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I need to customize a react-select dropdown a bit.  Its a multi-select, and my goal is that when the user select many options, the selected options only take up as much horizontal space in the box as is available.  Overflow should be handled with an ellipse.

Default behavior - overflow items wrap to next line and make box height grow:

[image]

Desired behavior - custom rendering, with ellipse

[image]

My tactic in accomplishing this is to use a custom component in the select for `ValueContainer`:

```js
const ValueContainer = (props) => (
  <div
    {...props.innerProps}
    style={{
      whiteSpace: "nowrap",
      overflow: "hidden",
      textOverflow: "ellipsis",
    }}
  >
    {props.selectProps?.value?.map((p) => p.label).join(", ")}
  </div>
);



const MyComponent = () => {
  // state logic here

  return (
     <Select
        options={options}
        value={value}
        isMulti
        onChange={(value) => setValue(value)}
        components={{ ValueContainer }}
      />
  );
```

This is indeed working, as you can see in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-default-value-forked-0z634n?file=/index.js:1567-1848).

However, I seem to have lost the default behavior.  In the left example in the sandbox (default as shown above), when you click on *any* part of the dropdown (existing selection, empty space, dropdown indicator, etc), the dropdown opens.  This is the behavior I want.  In my custom example, clicking on the list *does not* open the dropdown - you have to click specifically on the tiny little dropdown arrow to get it to open.  Likewise, when its open, the default behavior has a click-away handler, where clicking anywhere on the screen closes the menu.  That behavior is also lost with this custom `ValueContainer` component.

How can I maintain this custom open/close click behavior, while using a custom `ValueContainer` component?  There does not seem to be an `innerRef` on the props of a `ValueContainer`, as described in the docs.  Is there a `setOpen` prop somewhere in these props that I'm missing?  Is there a better way to achieve my desired effect?